# Importing text in Google Sheets using Importhtml

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, substitution

What should be changed to allow the IMPORTHTML to retrieve a text value?

I get this error message; "Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values.  But "Distribution Rate" is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

```
=if(isblank($A17),"",(substitute(index(importhtml("https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/"&A17,"table",2),2,1),"*",""))*1)
```

Comment: Remove the `*1` bit.

Comment: Thanks 'doubleunary'.  Perfect answer, simple but right on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A17),,(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/"&A17, "table", 2), 2, 1), "*", )))
```